# Failover server virtualization, what solution?

Tags: linux, virtualization, failover

I currently have a web/mail server with mutiple virtual domains on it.

I would like to run a failover server (all my dns are already on an failover ip), keep it in sync with the main server. Thus when I want to upgrade the system or a package on the main server, I can switch to my failover server, pause the sync process, do my stuffs on the main server and then, run the sync again and switch back to the main server.

I've tried a syncing solution via csync2 and lsync, but I also have an administration panel application (WHM/cPanel) and I can't sync all files mainly because most of them store the real ip address, not the failover one.

Here why I'm looking for a virtualization solution, but I have no idea of how to do that.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You either get rid of cPanel, or you do it _their way_. Whatever that is.

Comment: I have edited my post, hoping it is much clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any virtualisation solution on the market allows you to make snapshots of a system, and even deploy a clone of that system from those snapshots, using vmware, xen, kvm or hyper-v does not matter. The change in process for you would be.

make a snapshot of your virtual machine.
Upgrade software.
Test.
delete snapshot / roll back to snapshot

In the case of having to upgrade the virtual machine host, running with 2 of these machines will allow you to seamlessly migrate virtual machines from one to the next if the configuration is done right (shared storage, etc).

Comment: If I understand, the idea is to have two physical hosts, each one running a virtual machine.